# Where does the word “minge” come from?

Tags: etymology, british-english, slang, offensive-language

The slang term *minge* in the sense of [*quim*](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/142492) dates from the beginning of the 20<sup>th</sup> century. However, neither the OED nor Etymonline has any idea where it came from.

Here are two of the OED’s citations:

- 1936 J. Curtis *Gilt Kid* viii. 80 — I’m going to give you a kick in the **minge** if you don’t shut up. 
  1974 *New Direction* IV. iv. 19/2 — They’ve all..scented and talced their **minges**.

Which is all very nice and all, but what is the origin of the word in this sense?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question was actually the subject of a paper: [**Minge --- A Loanword Study**](http://www.academia.edu/2131412/Minge-a_Loanword_Study) by James Clackson. Clackson asserts that *minge* is, like  *pal*, *nark*, and *lollipop*, a **loanword** from Romani Gypsy. While the OED dates the first use of *minge* in text as 1903, it had been used since the 19th century in (very) informal conversation --- it belonged almost solely to spoken English, and even then, appeared to have been commonly used only by speakers of certain dialects.

However, to complicate matters, the origin of *minge* in the Romani language itself is somewhat uncertain. Clackson suggests that it came into the Romani language as a loanword from Armenian.

The origin of *minge* is rather interesting --- I suggest you read the paper. It should adequately answer your question.